# printing row from 2D array

Tags: arrays, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = (
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
);
my @second_row = @{ $array[1] };
print "Second row: [@second_row]\n";
```

getting output as : Second row: [5 6 7 8]
but i need it as  : Second row: [5, 6, 7, 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [the `join` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html). Try something like:

```
print "Second row: [", join(', ', @second_row), "]\n";
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly.I tried using join but was missing comma that you placed after and before double quotes !!